# Invoke method assigned to SelectedIndexChanged event of a DDL

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, controls, selectedindexchanged

I have a routine that puts some data (from an SQL query) into some controls. It works. Note I'm only using two kinds of controls in this instance - TextBox and DropDownList. There are some fields on the form that need to be set based on the value in one of these controls.  During data entry, this happens by the firing of a SelectedIndexChanged event.  But I would like to do this automatically in this subroutine.  I can see a couple of different solutions, none of which I know how to implement.  I have a very tacky solution I do not like.  I treat the problem control separately.  I would like to modify this routine to fire the SelectedIndexChanged method, but only if it exists.

```
    // Put a row's value into a control
    // 
    private void assign_value_to_control(string control_name, DataRow row, string col_name )
    {
        Control c = ControlExtensions.FindControlRecursive(this.Page, control_name);
        if (c == null)
        {
            // log an error message that control was not found?
            return;
        }

        if (row[col_name] == DBNull.Value)
        {
            // No value in the column ... don't assign value to control.
            return;
        }

        if (c is DropDownList) { ((DropDownList) c).SelectedValue = row[col_name].ToString();  }
        if (c is TextBox) { ((TextBox)c).Text = row[col_name].ToString(); }

    }
```

Problem: Fire the SelectedIndexChanged event when appropriate from inside this method.

Solution 1: pass an optional method name to the routine.  Not sure how to implement this in C#.  For most of the controls, there is no method, so I would pass null, but I'm not sure how to pass the name of a method.

Solution 2: Pass a flag telling it to invoke the specific method ... this seems even tackier than my current solution.

Solution 3: Given a control, look for a method that is bound to the SelectedIndexChanged event.  I know something like this should be possible, but I could use a little help figuring it out.

I would like to know how to implement both solutions 1 and 3, but my preference is solution 3 - look for a method tied to that event and then invoke it, if it exists.

Any pointers?

I have figured out how to implement solution 1.

```
private void assign_value_to_control(string control_name, DataRow row, string col_name, Action<object,EventArgs> method)
{
    Control c = ControlExtensions.FindControlRecursive(this.Page, control_name);
    if (c == null)
    {
        // log an error message that control was not found?
        return;
    }

    if (row[col_name] == DBNull.Value)
    {
        // No value in the column ... don't assign value to control.
        return;
    }

    if (c is DropDownList) { ((DropDownList) c).SelectedValue = row[col_name].ToString();  }
    if (c is TextBox) { ((TextBox)c).Text = row[col_name].ToString(); }

    if (method == null)
    {
        Class1.WebAudit("debug1", "null method passed to assign_value_to_control()");
    }
    else
    {
        Class1.WebAudit("debug1", "method passed to assign_value_to_control()");
        method(c, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

}
```

I then invoke as:

```
assign_value_to_control("ddlQ7" + rowNumber, row, "MeasurementUnits", ddlQ7_SelectedIndexChanged)
```

to invoke the method or as

```
assign_value_to_control("ddlQ7" + rowNumber, row, "MeasurementUnits", null)
```

to assign a value without invoking any methods.

I think I would still prefer to do this as in Solution 3 (which I still don't quite know how to do).